# Google tests don't work with class in other project in solution

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, googletest

I'm trying to test my simple class for building (that it has good constructor).
File `TestClass.h`

```
#pragma once

class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass();
};
```

File `TestClass.cpp`

```
#include "TestClass.h"

TestClass::TestClass()
{
}
```

And then I add new project in my solution: `tests`. This project contains only one file.
File `test.cpp`

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "../Example/TestClass.h"

TEST(Test0, all)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(true, true);
}

/*
TEST(Test1, part1)
{
    TestClass t;
}*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

If I build that code - all is good (and all tests). But if I uncomment commented block - I have such output with error:

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Example, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  TestClass.cpp
>   1>  Example.vcxproj -> d:\Alex\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\tests\Debug\Example.lib
>   2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: tests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   2>  test.cpp
>   2>test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TestClass::TestClass(void)" (??0TestClass@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall Test1_part1_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@Test1_part1_Test@@EAEXXZ)
>   2>d:\Alex\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\tests\Debug\tests.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>   ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I added `gtest.lib` file to dependency of linker input of `tests` project.
I added `Example` project as a dependency of `tests` project.
I built `Example` project as Static library (.lib).
If I delete constructor from `TestClass` - all will be good.
My project you can find [here](https://yadi.sk/d/1Z8E3hWV3GyKBs).
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 on Windows 10 Pro x64.
My Google Test Framework version is 1.8.0.

How can I solve this compilation problem? I really need this constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve this problem:
I manually add `buildDir` (to me it was `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\`) to that way:
**`tests` properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library directories**
And I manually add `Example.lib` dependency to that way:
**`tests` properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies**

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly the problem I encounted now. Solution is as follow:

- Make sure you add the ***Reference***: under **Test Project**, add reference to the **Source Project**.
- Set the ***Configuration Properties*** of the project contains *TestClass.cpp* and *TestClass.h* as ***Static library***: In VS 2015, it's under *Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Project Defaults -> Configuration Type*. Besides, comment out the main function in **Source Project**.

Hope it helps.:)